# how to maintain updated user flows on product team walls

Tags: user-journey, flowcharts, flow, journey-map

So far, what we do is simply take a large print out of the current feature we are working on and stick it on the wall. As brainstorming sessions and discussions happen about the feature, notes, scribbles and soon enough the printout needs to be updated with a new one as changes need to be made.

What's the best way to maintain updated user flow without having to make a new printout every time something in it changes? i'm thinking of a more modular approach as separate printouts per screen or stickers for each UI element. but that might be too granular.

What would be the best solution for this, and are there any best practices for this already?

Comment: Based on the term "print out", I assume it's a digital source. The obvious suggestion would then be to have a dedicated computer and television on the wall connected to it that you could display the new user flow chart on as soon as it was ready. Are there any reasons (financial limitations, etc), that preclude this?

Comment: Digital whiteboards also come to mind.

Comment: yes. there would be financial limitations for this. so taking constant printout or getting a high cost device like a digital white board might not be an option

Comment: In that case, you may like to consider some sort of shared synchronized scrapbooking tool like Microsoft OneNote which people could interact with on a laptop during the brainstorm.

Or perhaps a used/refurbished TV, projector or some sort of small screen that's within your budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical representations are usually good if it is done for high level processes or workflows that don't change frequently.

As pointed out in the comments, digital solutions are much more flexible and scalable. The same type of interactivity as a physical board can also be replicated if there is a touch screen.

One suggestion/advice that would make your life easier is to have a standardised way to document the workflow across project teams so that you can easily scale the level of detail that you want to represent the workflow.